# get icon in drawer route in createStackNavigators initialRoute nested inside createDrawerNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a createDrawerNavigator with a drawer on left and a createStackNavigator nested inside.
Im trying to get icons for every route in drawer but for createStackNavigators initialRoute, icons are not appearing[image]

As there is no icon present in front of profile, its a createStackNavigator 
and how do i acheive that.

Code:
App.js file with navigation structure

```
const MainNavigation = createDrawerNavigator(
{
  Home: ProductsScreen,
  Cart: CartScreen,
  Profile: createStackNavigator(
  {
    profilepage: ProfileScreen,
    form: ProfileFormScreen
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "profilepage",
    mode: "card",
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  }),
  Order: OrderScreen,
  Reminder: ReminderScreen
})
```

Now here, the nested createStackNavigator does not catches the icon.

In drawer navigator, every screen catches icon as static navigationOptions are given in their screen classes...

like:

```
static navigationOptions = {
  drawerIcon: (
    <Icon
      name="home"
      color="#007aff"
      type="materialicons"
      style={{ height: 24, width: 24 }}
    />
  )
}; <-- This is for like home screen in drawer, the same i have done in ProfileScreen as well, but its not working.
```

ProfileScreen code for icon:

```
static navigationOptions = {
  drawerIcon: (
    <Icon
      name="user"
      color="#007aff"
      type="font-awesome"
      style={{ height: 24, width: 24 }}
    />
  )
};
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: i'm guessing the order icon is the one missing, right ?

Comment: @kivul just edited the question...

Comment: @Macromeda the icon for profile is not appearing, i dont know why